# Pyinstaller changing csv file output, however when running it as Python the csv file output is correct

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

Please can someone help me with an issue I'm having with pyinstaller.

Thanks to the help I received on here I have finally got the python code fully working, even if not the prettiest and I'm sure I can improve on that as I learn.

This code now asks the user to select the csv file they wish to clean of text "(1) (2) (3)" and then removes that text and then asks the user what file name they wish to save it as and it works perfectly when I run on my Mac, including adding the .csv to the saved file name.

When I transfer this to my Windows 10 machine and use pyinstaller --onefile csv_cleaner.py it goes through the making of the exe without any errors and the exe opens and runs, however,
1: the first difference is that is no longer adds .csv to the filename being saved, I need to remember to add this.

2: It now adds an empty row between every existing row

A raw csv file would be

Part Number   Quantity
abcd12(1)        5
df2wue(3)        10
qn872n(2)        2

Which when run as python it correctly produces the output

Part Number   Quantity
abcd12           5
df2wue           10
qn872n           2

However after Pyinstaller has made it into the exe the output is
Part Number   Quantity

abcd12           5

df2wue           10

qn872n           2

here is my code, I'm using dropna() and index=False. I would very much appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction of getting this to work as it should following the use of pyinstaller. Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import messagebox


def askfle():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw() 
    filepath = askopenfilename() 

    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

    df.replace(r" \(1\)", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
    df.replace(r" \(2\)", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
    df.replace(r" \(3\)", "", regex=True, inplace=True)

    Data_Cleaned = df.dropna()
    
    data = [(' ', 'csv')] 
    file_out = asksaveasfile(filetypes=data, defaultextension=data,initialfile = " ")
    Data_Cleaned.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding="utf-8")




def messageatend():
    messagebox.showinfo('Title', 'Your file has been cleaned of numbers in brackets and saved \n\nClick on Ok to Exit')

def messageendornot():
    res = messagebox.askquestion('askquestion', 'Would you like to clean another CSV file?')
    if res == 'yes':
        askfle()
        messageatend()
        messageendornot()



askfle()
messageatend()
messageendornot()
```

Comment: .to_csv will try to overwrite or generate new file

Comment: Thanks #Nanthakumar J J. I'm not sure I understand what you mean though? It is a new file and the name and location comes from asksaveasfile, plus when I run this as a .py on my Mac it works perfectly, however as soon as I put it on to my windows machine and use pyinstaller to get a exe file, it still works, however it no longer works as it should. I'm using the to_csv tomato the new file, I just don't understand where the blank rows are coming from?

Comment: Can you try this `df.dropna(axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nanthakumar J J, I've tried as you suggest and it deletes the whole first column and just leaves one column with the quantities which still has a blank row in between each row. Frustrating because when I run the code on my Mac it works perfectly. Perhaps I should try and clean up the data but just read the CSV rather than using pandas. Thanks again for your suggestions.